# $\int\frac{x}{(x\tan x+1)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

$$ \int\frac{x}{(x\tan x+1)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x = \int x \frac{\cot^2 x}{(x+\cot x)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x.$$

By parts method gives
$$-\frac{x}{x+\cot x}+\int\frac{1}{x+\cot x}\,\mathrm{d}x,$$
and how to solve it?

Comment: While I am on a time crunch, something tells me that you need to "reverse" the quotient rule to get back to the original function. Why? Because the denominator is squared.